# Поиск по базе данных на PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Помогите, пожалуйста. Не получается осуществить поиск по базе данных.

```html
<?php
include "connect.php";

?>

  <?php

$search_slovo = $_POST['q'];
if(isset($search_slovo)){
if(empty($search_slovo)) {exit ("Вы не ввели данные");}}

echo " Вы искали: $search_slovo";
$query= mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Кабинеты WHERE Номер_аудитории = ['$search_slovo']"); //строка 14

$result= mysqli_num_rows($query); //строка 16
if ($result == null)
{
echo "Sorry, I couldn’t find any user that matches your query ($search_slovo)";
exit; 
}
else if ($result == 1)
{
echo "I’ve found <b>1</b> match!<br>";
}
else {
echo "I’ve found <b>$result</b> matches! <br>";
}

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$nomer = $row["Номер_аудитории"];
$name = $row["Название_аудитории"];
}

echo "The middle name of the user is: $nomer.<br>";
echo "The last name of the user is: $name. <br>";
?>
```

**Ошибки:**

> **Warning**: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   W:\domains\localhost\www\poisk.php on line 14
>
> **Warning**: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in W:\domains\localhost\www\poisk.php on line 16

Comment: скопируйте код и ошибки в вопрос, картинки сложно читаются.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что сообщение с вопросом должно содержать __код__, а не изображение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка из за того что нужно передать параметр подключения в функцию `mysqli_query` а Вы передали только SQL запрос.

Посмотрите [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php).

Ещё, Ваш код требует много правок.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте оператор поиска LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%';
```

Answer (score -1):

На 14й строке mysqli_query( $DB, "ВАШ ЗАПРОС");
Перед вашим запросом добавте переменную которую присваивали к подключению к бд